# Identify if a mesh has "changed" after being linked to another mesh object

Tags: python

I have two objects which are facing opposite direction but their local origin rotation value are the same. If I link any of them to the other one, the selected one will rotate its mesh as it supposed to, but is there a way for a script to identify that case and re-orient back the linked mesh?

In this gif you can see what happens when the objects get linked and the manual Z rotation (I made manually) of the chair is what I would like for the script to identify and do it automatically.
Not sure if this is even possible.

[image]

I bet this is very rudimentary approach, but now I have managed to compare its own original vector against the one after being linked to another object of the same shape but different origin orientation, not sure if this is good or is it going on the wrong road:

I feel I'm getting closer, I have managed to loop through all the selected objects and ignoring the active one.
How I could select **only** the objects that are marked as "HAS CHANGED" in the script?

```
import bpy

active_ob = bpy.context.object #ACTIVE OBJECT

for objs in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if objs != active_ob: #IGNORES ACTIVE OBJECT
        old_v = objs.data.vertices[0].co
        old_mat = objs.matrix_world
        old_loc = old_mat @ old_v
        
        bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(type='OBDATA')

        new_v = objs.data.vertices[0].co
        new_mat = objs.matrix_world
        new_loc = new_mat @ new_v
        
        if old_loc != new_loc:
            print('HAS CHANGED')
            
        else:
            print('NO CHANGE')
```

Comment: apply rotation to each object before linking?  (CTRL-A and select rotation)

Comment: Thank you, I just tried your suggestion, but sadly didn't work because it will reset the orientation of each object to the world axis.

Comment: Doh.  I should have known that. sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Nah, no worries, we have to try everything anyway so we can discard what won't work. :)

Comment: Linking doesn't rotate mesh. Instead it links the mesh of the active object to all other objects. Try it by modifying one of the chairs (e.g. removing a seat) and then applying your method.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that is not a real rotation, but visually speaking only. If the another chair would have its origin rotated 180° then you wouldn't see it become "rotated". Therefore, I have been thinking on comparing each object to be linked against itself and if the vector changes then that object will be ignored or do something else.

Comment: Perhaps a better phrasing of the question would be "Identify if a mesh is **changed**". To do that, you can just iterate over all vertices and return `True` at first coordinates difference, otherwise return `False` after iteration. Identifying if a mesh is "rotated" requires clarification - do you want to see if a mesh is changed only by rotation but otherwise not changed?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I updated the title as you suggested.
When I run the my script it does what I'm looking after, the thing is that I don't know how to apply the old_loc back to that object.
I used the term rotate because that's the issue I have with this, if I replace all the chairs in my scene with a table on front of them, if one of those chairs has the origin rotated it will be intersecting with the table so that's the situation I want to tackle.

Comment: I have updated the code a little bit, getting closer (I think)

Comment: Perhaps your problem would be more easily solved upstream, how do you end up in this situation ?

Comment: When getting files from clients in FBX format, I need to streamline the object replacement. If an object is mirroed in archicad the object will be interpreted as a different one, but if an object in archicad is only duplicated, it comes as linked.

Comment: You can filter out objects which share the same data with `if objs.data == context.active_object.data: continue`. Otherwise define a list before your loop like `changed_objects = []` and `if old_loc != new_loc: changed_objects.append(objs)` (Btw consider using `obj` instead of `objs` the plural form indicates there are several objects when the variable points to a single object) :)